# Audio issue on mkv to m3u8 conversion using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I'm using the following command to convert mkv AUDIO to aac in the aim of using it in a m3u8 file with others audio playlist but both hls.js and videojs seems to be unable to read it dropping issues messages.

I'm using the example of hls.js which works with others ex-mp4 files (m3u8 converted).

**The code**

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mkv -threads 0 -muxdelay 0 -y -map 0:a:0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -codec copy -f hls audio/audio.m3u8
```

I tried also

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mkv -threads 0 -muxdelay 0 -y -map 0:a:0 -codec copy -ac 6 -b:a 384k -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list audio/audio.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts audio/audio_%d.aac
```

And

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mkv -threads 0 -muxdelay 0 -y -map 0:a:0 -codec copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list audio/audio.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts audio/audio_%d.aac
```

**The error message dropped by hls.js**

```
208.382 | Parsing error:Found no media in msn 0 of level "audio/audio.m3u8"
208.628 | Parsing error:Found no media in msn 1 of level "audio/audio.m3u8"
208.966 | Parsing error:Found no media in msn 2 of level "audio/audio.m3u8"
209.286 | Parsing error:Found no media in msn 3 of level "audio/audio.m3u8"
209.601 | Parsing error:Found no media in msn 4 of level "https://atraxia.tk/stockage/disk_2/m3u8/test/audio-fr/audio-fr.m3u8"
209.92 | Parsing error:Found no media in msn 5 of level "audio/audio.m3u8"
210.176 | Parsing error:Found no media in msn 6 of level "audio/audio.m3u8"
210.178 | A media error occurred: fragParsingError
```

With .aac

```
0.508 | Error while loading fragment audio/audio_0.aac
0.596 | Error while loading fragment audio/audio_0.aac
0.666 | Error while loading fragment audio/audio_0.aac
0.757 | Error while loading fragment audio/audio_0.aac
0.814 | Error while loading fragment audio/audio_0.aac
0.875 | Error while loading fragment audio/audio_0.aac
0.951 | Error while loading fragment audio/audio_0.aac
0.955 | A network error occurred: fragLoadError
```

As it works for other files converted such as mp4 I assume that it is a codec problem with the mkv file.

Comment: You're trying to play this in a browser? Doesn't HTML5 not support MKV (Matroska) files? If MP4 works than that's the case and you shouldn't bother with trying to get MKV to work via any magical libs.

Comment: See [How to playback MKV video in web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192713/how-to-playback-mkv-video-in-web-browser).

Comment: @oxou the aim is to convert mkv into m3u8 with ffmpeg so it can be played in the browser, but in some cases it doesn't works due to the audio track